# Why can't this table compile?

Tags: tables, xepersian

I had wrote following table in TexMaker, when I write it without `\usepackage{xepersian}` it works but when I want to compile it with that package too, program will hang! But I don't see any mistakes and my entries are these.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}‎‎
\usepackage{xepersian}‎
\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar}‎‎
\author{SadeghiManesh}
\title{A Table}
\begin{document}
    ‎\begin{flushleft}
    ‎\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline $\nabla_{X_{i}}X_{j}$ & $\Gamma_{i,j}^{2}$ & $\Gamma_{i,j}^{1}$ & k & j & i  \\ 
    \hline $\frac{-1}{x_{2}}X_{2}$ & $‎\begin{array}{l} ‎\;‎ \\ \frac{-1}{x_{2}} \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} - \\ ‎\;‎ \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} $‎‎ \\ 
    \hline $\frac{-1}{x_{2}}X_{1}‎‎$‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} ‎\;‎ \\ - \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} \frac{-1}{x_{2}} \\ ‎\;‎ \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 2 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} $‎‎ \\ 
    \hline $\frac{-1}{x_{2}}X_{1}$ & $‎\begin{array}{l} ‎\;‎ \\ - \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} \frac{-1}{x_{2}} \\ ‎\;‎ \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 2 ‎‎\end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 2 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ \\ 
     \hline $\frac{-3}{x_{2}}X_{2}$ & $‎\begin{array}{l} ‎\;‎ \\ \frac{-3}{x_{2}} \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} - \\ ‎\;‎ \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 2 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 2 \\  2\end{array} $‎‎ \\ 
     \hline 
     \end{tabular} ‎
     \end{flushleft}‎‎
\end{document}‎
```

Comment: First of all remove the call to the `inputenc` package. Are you using XeLaTeX to compile the document when `xepersian` is loaded?

Comment: @egreg , yes I use XeLaTex, when I want to compile a tex that will use xe-packages. But about inputenc?

Comment: The package `inputenc` should *never* be used with XeLaTeX. In your source there are many strange invisible characters, which may be the cause for the problem. If I use the Scheherazade font and remove the invisible characters, the table compiles.

Comment: @egreg , I had removed \usepackage[latin1]{inputnec} but my file doesn't work yet! and about invisible characters, I don't anything, all my file is above.

Answer (score 6):

As @egreg commented you have control characters in your preamble. If I convert the characters into Unicode names, you will see after most of your `\usepackage` lines you have BIDI controls. If you just delete the line and retype it just with the ascii characters then things work better. Also remove `inputenc`.

Note that they produces *errors* ie TeX should stop with a message. It then more or less hangs or at least takes ages looking for the font, so I changed it to Arial. The result is at the end.

```
LATIN SMALL LETTER U
LATIN SMALL LETTER S
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LATIN SMALL LETTER P
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER C
LATIN SMALL LETTER K
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER G
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LEFT CURLY BRACKET
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER M
LATIN SMALL LETTER S
LATIN SMALL LETTER S
LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
LATIN SMALL LETTER M
LATIN SMALL LETTER B
RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
LINE FEED (LF)
LINE FEED (LF)
REVERSE SOLIDUS
LATIN SMALL LETTER U
LATIN SMALL LETTER S
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LATIN SMALL LETTER P
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER C
LATIN SMALL LETTER K
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER G
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LEFT CURLY BRACKET
LATIN SMALL LETTER X
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LATIN SMALL LETTER P
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
LATIN SMALL LETTER R
LATIN SMALL LETTER S
LATIN SMALL LETTER I
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER N
RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
LINE FEED (LF)
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xepersian}
%\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar}‎‎
\settextfont{Arial}
\author{SadeghiManesh}
\title{A Table}
\begin{document}
    ‎\begin{flushleft}
    ‎\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline $\nabla_{X_{i}}X_{j}$ & $\Gamma_{i,j}{2}$ & $\Gamma_{i,j}^{1}$ & k & j & i  \\ 
    \hline $\frac{-1}{x_{2}}X_{2}$ & $‎\begin{array}{l} ‎\;‎ \\ \frac{-1}{x_{2}} \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} - \\ ‎\;‎ \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} $‎‎ \\ 
    \hline $\frac{-1}{x_{2}}X_{1}‎‎$‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} ‎\;‎ \\ - \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} \frac{-1}{x_{2}} \\ ‎\;‎ \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 2 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} $‎‎ \\ 
    \hline $\frac{-1}{x_{2}}X_{1}$ & $‎\begin{array}{l} ‎\;‎ \\ - \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} \frac{-1}{x_{2}} \\ ‎\;‎ \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 2 ‎‎\end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 2 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ \\ 
     \hline $\frac{-3}{x_{2}}X_{2}$ & $‎\begin{array}{l} ‎\;‎ \\ \frac{-3}{x_{2}} \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} - \\ ‎\;‎ \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 2 \\ 2 \end{array} $‎‎ & $‎\begin{array}{l} 2 \\  2\end{array} $‎‎ \\ 
     \hline 
     \end{tabular} ‎
     \end{flushleft}‎‎
\end{document}
```